# Using Linked Lists in Checkerbox selection List react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, linked-list

I created a Linked-List data structure in my react-native app that I want to move between screens and then pick a node based on a checkerbox selection menu.

I understand that I can move the list using react-native-navigation, so now I would like to display the list with a checkerbox list to select multiple nodes and perform actions on them. The problem I see is that checkerbox lists use defined const arrays of items that are then listed.

The whole reason I went with linked-lists is that I need the list to dynamically update. (It may be more beneficial to use an array of large size instead, but each element within the node is somewhat large and I am unsure what effect a large array would have.)

Is there a way to input a linked list into a checkerbox list or would I have to create an array?

How would I go about either option if they need to dynamically update?

Answer (score 0):

> It may be more beneficial to use an array of large size instead, but each element within the node is somewhat large and I am unsure what effect a large array would have.

JavaScript arrays **only hold references to the objects they store** since it is a dynamic scripting language supporting prototype based **object** construction. Because of this, each **element's *size* will not affect the array performance**.

Another possibility is to extend the built-in `Array` class in your Linked-List data structure to ensure compatibility.

Your decision on using an Array or a Linked-List should be based on the List operations your app uses the most. [There are a lot of articles about that](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/linked-list-vs-array).

> Is there a way to input a linked list into a checkerbox list or would
>   I have to create an array?
>
> How would I go about either option if they need to dynamically update?

There are some **git repositories** that add support for what you want to achieve ([here is an example](https://github.com/Rinkuk1993/rn-checkbox-list), feel free to explore npm for more).

Another possibility, if you want your items to dynamically update, will be to **encapsulate them in a React.Component** for rendering:

```js
// YourNode.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native';

export default class YourNode extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
    };
  }

  selectItem = () => {
    const { onPress } = this.props;
    // Update the state
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    onPress();
  };

  render() {
    const { node } = this.props;
    // You may want to render more things like `Text` or `View` components based on
    // the node's content
    return (
    <CheckBox
      value={this.state.checked}
      onValueChange={this.selectItem}
    />
    );
  }
}

import YourNode from './YourNode';

// YourScreen.js

render() {
  //...
  // This will render a `YourNode` component for each one of your nodes.
  {yourList.map((item, index)) => {
      return (<YourNode node={item} onPress{() => this.selectedNodes.push(item)}>)
    }
  }
}
```